# Regex for alphanumeric plus underscores, but not just numbers

Tags: regex, pcre

I need a regex for strings containing letters, numbers and underscores in any order, but may not consist of numbers alone. This far I have:

`^[a-zA-Z_]+[0-9]*$`

But that won't allow `123hello_` even though it should. 
Strings that should match:

```
abc123
123_
_123abc
abc_123
_ABC
123_ABC_
```

Strings that should not match:

```
1234
hellö
abc%
```

Comment: Try like [`^\d*[_a-zA-Z]\w*$`](https://regex101.com/r/sjQhKB/3/)